# Add a MultiFieldPanel in Django Wagtail BaseSettings

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin, wagtail

I am adding a set of fields that can can be filled out by my users in Wagtail Admin. Everything works good, but I want to organize the settings in panel groups, but its not working.  Can someone please review my code below and see if I am doing this correctly?

```
...
from wagtail.contrib.settings.models import BaseSetting, register_setting
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import MultiFieldPanel, FieldPanel


@register_setting
class SiteSettings(BaseSetting):
    facebook = models.URLField(blank=True, help_text='Your Facebook page URL')
    instagram = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, help_text='Your Instagram username, without the @')
    youtube = models.URLField(blank=True, help_text='Your YouTube channel or user account URL')
    company_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250, help_text='Enter your company name how you would like it to appear on the site')

    content_panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel('facebook'),
                FieldPanel('instagram'),
                FieldPanel('youtube'),
            ],
            heading="Social Media Profiles",
            classname="collapsible collapsed"
        ),
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel('company_name'),
            ],
            heading="Company Info",
            classname="collapsible collapsed"
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/settings.html#edit-handlers, you should use `panels`, not `content_panels`.

(The name `content_panels`, used on Wagtail pages, comes from the fact that it affects the "Content" tab, as opposed to "Promote" or "Settings". For the settings and snippets modules, there are no tabs by default - so it's simply called `panels`.)

Comment: Worked like a charm!!  Thank you!